# How do correlated sub-queries work?

Tags: sql

Consider a schema like

```
create table world 
(
    name varchar(255), 
    continent varchar(255), 
    area varchar(255)
);

insert into world values("Germany", "Europe", 20);
insert into world values("France", "Europe", 10);
insert into world values("Russia", "Europe", 30);
insert into world values("China", "Asia", 10);
insert into world values("Japan", "Asia", 20);
```

Then executing this query

```
select name, continent, area 
from world t1
where area >= all (select area 
                   from world t2 
                   where t1.continent = t2.continent);
```

will list the largest country by area for each continent.

Here is the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a66aee/4/0

What I understand from this **[article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/correlated-vs-uncorrelated-subquery/)** is that it processes each of the outer row and then proceeds to inner query.

If my understanding is right, then

for 1st outer row,

```
name = Germany, continent= Europe, area = 20
```

the inner-query would then look like

```
select area from world t2 where t2.continent = "Europe";
```

which would return area like this:

```
20
10
30
```

The outer query would then check

```
if t1.area >= 20, 10 and 30 .....(t1.area = 20)
```

which should return `20 and 30`.

If that's the case, then should it not return the rows:

```
"Germany", "Europe", 20
"Russia",  "Europe", 30
```

If this is not right then how does SQL process a correlated query?

Comment: Because the resulting query would look like `select name, continent, area from world t1 where t1.area >=20 `. But I see your point. if its processing interatively then it should just return Germany

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `"Germany"` is not a valid character constant in SQL. Character values need to be enclosed in single quotes in (standard) SQL.

Comment: I am not using any DBMS, I was trying to learn Sql using http://sqlzoo.net/ tutorials. They provide query input fields for each question, this makes it easy for me to check the result instantly. Also double quotes seems to work fine in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You can't run SQL without any DBMS. You always have some DBMS which runs the SQL.  assume that you are using MySQL in SQLFiddle which ignores and violates the standard in many ways. If you want to learn _correct_ SQL I suggest you use a DBMS that sticks closer to the SQL standard.  Try running those statement with e.g. Postgres (or Oracle) in SQFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you understood the basics, but not the ending.

Yes, the is how the query will be processed, except this part:

```
if t1.area >= 20, 10 and 30 .....(t1.area = 20)
```

Your query checks if the currect `t1.area` which is now `20` is larger then `ALL` the values provided in the sub query, which for that row are `(10,20,30)` .
Since `20` is smaller then `30` , then this condition is `FALSE`, so this row from the outer query will be filtered.

For `Europe` only area `30` should be returned, since its the only one bigger then all of the sub query results `30>= 10 && 30>= 20 && 30>= 30`

Comment: I see, I had misunderstood `all`